# Prestashop if Statement for Homepage w/ FB Like Button

Tags: facebook, prestashop

Having a bit of an issue. I want a facebook button to only social up on the homepage in my blocksocial module so I put this code in the unordered list on the blocksocial tpl file.

```
{if $page_name == 'index'}<div class="share-buttons share-buttons-fb-like" data-style="button_count" style="padding-top:5px;"></div>{/if}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Is this something to do with the fact that it is the Facebook like button?

Issue can be seen at www[dot]anewall[dot]com.

Tried the Prestashop forums but no luck so far. Would appreciate any help!

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is wrong with this as `if $page_name == 'index'` seems valid.

However there is an alternative approach for this that you can use in your module -  you can display different content, and do diffrent things (assign different tpl files for example) from the same hook, depending on the current page

```
if('index' == $this->context->controller->php_self)
    // Do something and display a template for the homepage
```

More info can be found [in this blog post](http://nemops.com/page-specific-prestashop-module/)

Comment: Appreciate the help Sergei. I'm going to try this. :)

Answer (score 2):

In 1.7 you can use this code in your tpl file

```
{if $page.page_name == 'index'}
 ... YOUR CODE ...
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

To show stuff only on the homepage I have used this:

```
{if 'index' == $page_name }
    ... YOUR CODE ...
{/if}
```